# Why doesn't having a nonzero Zero State Response Invalidate Linearity for an LTI system?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can somebody point out the flaw in this logic? Its obviously wrong but I am not able to figure out what incorrect assumption was made.

The claim:

A Linear Time Invariant (LTI) system's output, $y(t)$, can be broken down into the Zero Input Response (ZIR) and  the Zero State Response (ZSR) like so:
$$y(t) = ZIR(t) + ZSR(t)$$

Say we have an LTI $L()$ whose input is $x(t)$ and output is $y(t)$. By definition, if $x(t) = 0, $ $\forall t$, then $$L(x(t)) = ZIR(t)$$.

Now lets say our input is $x(t) = 0 + 0, $ $\forall t$. Then by applying linearity and then the above definition, $$L(x(t)) = L(0 + 0) = L(0) + L(0) = 2ZIR(t)$$ Therefore the $ZIR(t)$ must be $0$ $\forall t$

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the first paragraph. You will have to define $ZIR(t)$ and $ZSR(t)$ in more detail.

If we start from
$$L(0) = ZIR(t)$$
Then your derivation of
$$ ZIR(t) = 2ZIR(t) $$
is correct, and the conclusion to draw from this is
$$ ZIR(t) = 0 $$
$$ L(0) = 0$$
In other words, the response of an LTI system to zero input is zero output

Comment: Thanks, my question does not really make sense. It was in refernce to Ordinary Differential equations, but I just realize I was framing the claim incorrectly.